# Proxy settings not working

Tags: linux, proxy, windows-xp, squid

I have set SQUID proxy server on my one of the machine '192.168.1.69'.

I assigned other machines GATEWAY to '192.168.1.69'.

I have set proxy for both windows (Start -> Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Lan Settings ) and linux (System -> Preferences -> Network proxy),but though I had to set proxy address on my browser.

I want to know is there any way to automatically set proxy address without any settings on browser.

Thanks !

Comment: This question belongs on http://serverfault.com/ where you're more likely to get answers from system administrators and desktop support professionals.

Answer (score 3):

Well the proxy may not be the gateway. If you want the proxy config to be automatic, this is called **transparent proxy**.

One way to do it, is using iptables on the gateway machine:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

You can find more information about this on wikipedia, or [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between a network proxy and an application (HTTP/HTTPS) proxy. Squid is the latter, which is why you had to set the proxy address in your browser.

Check out this link to set up a proxy config file that your browsers should read automatically:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361918.aspx